# Transpose specific column into single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view

I have Vehicle Path table in following order

| Vehicle_ID | Vehicle Path |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 |
| 1 | 55 |
| 1 | 136 |
| 2 | 50 |
| 2 | 65 |
| 2 | 75 |
| 3 | 101 |
| 3 | 105 |
| 3 | 110 |
| 3 | 125 |

I want result like below format.

| Vehicle_ID | Path1 | Path2 | Path3 | Path4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 55 | 136 |  |
| 2 | 50 | 65 | 75 |  |
| 3 | 101 | 105 | 110 | 125 |

I tried pivot method but I couldn't get result like above.

Comment: What happens if a `Vehicle_ID` has 5 or more rows for `Vehicle Path`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that there is no third column which maintains the actual relative ordering of the path values.  Assuming this order doesn't matter, we can pivot with the help of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Vehicle_ID
                                 ORDER BY Vehicle_ID) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    Vehicle_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN [Vehicle Path] END) AS Path1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN [Vehicle Path] END) AS Path2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN [Vehicle Path] END) AS Path3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN [Vehicle Path] END) AS Path4
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    Vehicle_ID
ORDER BY
    Vehicle_ID;
```

Comment: The hint about the sorting seems to be extremely important... Assuming the `path` points to some kind of route I'm pretty sure, that sorting matters...

Answer (score 1):

Another way, assuming SQL Server 2017 or better (and that you don't care about 5th and later rows for any given `Vehicle_ID`):

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT Vehicle_ID, 
    y = '["' + STRING_AGG(Vehicle_Path, '","') + '"]'
  FROM dbo.VehicleInfo
  GROUP BY Vehicle_ID
)
SELECT Vehicle_ID, 
  Path1 = JSON_VALUE(cte.y, '$[0]'),
  Path2 = JSON_VALUE(cte.y, '$[1]'),
  Path3 = JSON_VALUE(cte.y, '$[2]'),
  Path4 = JSON_VALUE(cte.y, '$[3]')
FROM cte;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2ee75814e19cc2411784efaa66788baf)

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness' sake, the `PIVOT` version would go like this:

```sql
SELECT p.Vehicle_ID, p.[1] AS Path1, p.[2] AS Path3, p.[3] AS Path3, p.[4] AS Path4
FROM (
  SELECT Vehicle_ID, Vehicle_Path, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Vehicle_ID ORDER BY Vehicle_ID) ix
  FROM dbo.VehicleInfo
) AS s
PIVOT (  
  AVG(Vehicle_Path)  
  FOR ix IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) as p;
```

Of course the order caveat noted in Tim Biegeleisen's answer applies to this solution as well (just like any other solution really).